# Adding a time to datetime

Tags: datetime, convert

I need some help correcting the time when doing a datetime convert. Currently when running the script below I get a time of 12:00AM - I need it to state 8:03AM

```
SELECT [custcode],[customername],[emailaddress],convert(datetime, [accstart], 109) AS [purchasedate] FROM [CustomerList]
```

Accstart references column with dates eg. 15-Nov-15, 2-MAY-15

Thanks for your help

Comment: is this ExactTarget? Please add a tag to the OP to get better support